# In Crystal Report First Item image is not showing

Tags: c#, windows, crystal-reports-2010

In Crystal Report the First Item image is not being displayed. It displays only the default image whereas I need to display dynamically from the database. It's working for all images except for the first image.

I just followed the below steps

1. Ad an image to the report using insert->picture
2. Right click on image -> format object ->picture
3. Change the formula of the graphic location

[image]

Comment: Is the second picture correct, or maybe showing the first one? Maybe add a hidden detail area before your acutal area and run the formula there

Comment: Did you try swapping the formula's? Can you show the formula's?

Comment: I am not using any formula. i have just passed my database field : EX {PO_INV.ItemImagepath}

Comment: Yes @davidbaumann sir,  Second picture is correct. only first picture is default as chosen for insertion time.

Comment: Is it always the same item which misses the picture? Or really always the first one.

Answer (score 0):

The above problem is occurred when we are displaying image from grid cell selection( for every items). By default first cell is selected , then image is open. Crystal report is not able to display image from same location. So due the this reason i was facing the above problem. Now i have disabled the functionality for cell selection or (can be used after clear the bitmap controls value on print functionality). Now crystal report is working fine.
Thanks to everyone.